# How to exclude classes from JPA Metamodel generation while keeping other generation libraries, like mapstruct and javax.validation, intact?

Tags: java, jpa, maven-plugin

I want JPA to generate metamodels only for those entities that are used in criteria. There seems to be no way to do it via usual maven plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.25.Final</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

so I tried to use maven processor plugin instead:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                     <exclude>...</exclude>
                <excludes>
                <processors>
                    <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                </processors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.25.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

However, while this approach kinda works, now my other generation units, mapstruct and javax.validation, stopped working, for instance:

```
[INFO] diagnostic warning: unknown enum constant javax.annotation.meta.When.MAYBE
  reason: class file for javax.annotation.meta.When not found
[ERROR] error on execute: error during compilation
```

Is there any way I can fix this while simultaneously keeping include/exclude feature of JPA Metamodel generation?

Comment: Did you find any better solution?

Comment: No, had to get rid of JPA Metamodel completely and use Lombok's @FieldNameConstants instead